# como hacer un else en php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo el cual actualiza los datos de una persona

```
$conexion = oci_connect('PROYECTO','presariocq43','localhost/XE');
            $q = oci_parse ($conexion,"UPDATE PACIENTE SET NOMBRE='$NOMBRE',
            APELLIDO='$APELLIDO',CORREO='$CORREO',EDAD='$EDAD',TELEFONO='$TELEFONO'
            ,DIRECCION='$DIRECCION' WHERE CEDULA_PACIENTE=$CEDULA");
            oci_execute($q);
            echo "Usuario modificado exitosamente";
```

quiero hacer un if con su respectivo else pero no se que estructura debe tener, lo ideal seria que si el usuario existe, muestre el mensaje exitoso, en caso de no encontrarlo, mostrar un mensaje de error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Convendría que blindes el código usando consultas preparadas.

Luego, tienes que verificar el estado de `oci_execute`, que retornará `false` cuando haya errores. Si te interesa, puedes capturar el error con `oci_error`.

Prueba de este modo:

```
<?php
    $conexion = oci_connect('PROYECTO','presariocq43','localhost/XE');
    #En vez de poner los valores directamente
    #lo cual es una puerta abierta a Inyección SQL
    #colocamos marcadores, nótese que no se usa comillas simples aquí
    #y que se usa a la derecha un marcador de :NOMBRE
    #que será el mismo en cada oci_bind_by_name
    $sql="UPDATE PACIENTE SET NOMBRE=:NOMBRE,
                APELLIDO=:APELLIDO,CORREO=:CORREO,EDAD=:EDAD,TELEFONO=:TELEFONO,
                DIRECCION=:DIRECCION WHERE CEDULA_PACIENTE=:CEDULA";
    $q = oci_parse ($conexion,$sql);
    #Aquí se pasan los valores de forma segura
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":NOMBRE", $NOMBRE);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":APELLIDO", $APELLIDO);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":CORREO", $CORREO);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":EDAD", $EDAD);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":TELEFONO", $TELEFONO);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":DIRECCION", $DIRECCION);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ":CEDULA", $CEDULA);
    #Verificamos si no hay error en la ejecución
    if ( oci_execute($q) ) {
        $msg="Se actualizaron {oci_num_rows($q)} fila(s)";
    } else {
        $e = oci_error($q);
        $msg="Hubo un error: $e[message]";
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: vaya pues gracias por ese aporte tan importante, la verdad no recordaba la inyeccion sql, aunque pues falta una cosa, como verifico que la busqueda encontro un dato, por ejemplo que en la base de datos tengo la cedula 1, el sistema si la actualizara, pero si pongo cedula de 1000, la cual no existe, pues me mostrara el mensaje de error diciendo que no esta en la base de datos

Comment: @Jose para eso primero debes hacer una consulta como esta `SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM PACIENTE WHERE CEDULA_PACIENTE=:CEDULA`  y verificar si el total de filas obtenidas es mayor que `0`. El `UPDATE` no te servirá jamás para saber con exactitud si un determinado registro existe o no en la base de datos y su finalidad no es esa, sino actualizar los datos, como bien indica su nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo , `oci_execute` te regresa un true si completa la consulta o un false en caso contrario, así que sería:

```
if (oci_execute($q)){
 echo "Usuario modificado exitosamente";
}else{echo "No se pudo modificar";}
```